# Excel view a 3d array when hovering

Tags: r, excel

I have output from R that I would like to put in excel. I think the best way to describe it would be as an array. I have 3 columns of analysis (point est, test stat, p value) for 14 variables from 50 analyses. What I would like to do is put them in an array in excel. What I ultimately would like to do is to be able to hover over a cell in a sheet, and see the corresponding values in the other sheets.

For example: On sheet 1 (this is my sheet of point estimates) in position B2 I have drug 1's point estimate for factor 1. On sheet 2 , B2, I have drug 1's test statistic for factor 1. On sheet 3 B2, I have drug 1's p value for factor 1.

what I want to happen is to hover over B2 on any sheet and see something like (point est=.5, chisq=1,pval=.3). In R, this is very easy to do (my_arr[1,1,]), but I'm quite inexperienced in excel, so I'm not even sure if this is something excel can do.

Is this possible to do in excel ?

Comment: Without getting too crazy with VBA - one way I suggest doing something like this is just to add comments to the cells you want a popup for.  This will result in the red triangle being in each cell, but if that's okay, I would say just write a script that places whatever value you want in the Comment.

Comment: Good idea, but that would not be dynamic, and it would probably take a reaaaalllyyy long time!

Comment: You could write something in VBA that would essentially dynamic.  Is it always going to be B2, on each sheet?  Is your Drug 1's info (point estimate factor, test statistic factor, p value) all in the same table? It wouldn't be too hard to just have the comment boxes look to the set location for each value.